# Как продублировать строки по разным id из одного столбца?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Работаю с файлом, загруженным в Jupyter Notebook.

Исходная таблица вида:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1','2,3','4,5,6','7'], 
    'name':['Ann','Alex','Mark','John'], 
    'city':['M','L','R','M']})
```

Нужно из нее получить таблицу вида:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'], 
    'name':['Ann','Alex','Alex','Mark','Mark','Mark','John'], 
    'city':['M','L','L','R','R','R','M']})
```

Т.е., если в `id` указано несколько значений, то нужно данную строку продублировать по каждому из них. Чтобы в итоге в столбце `id` было указано только по одному значению.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
res = df.assign(id=df["id"].str.split(",")).explode("id")
```

результат:

```
In [350]: res
Out[350]: 
  id  name city
0  1   Ann    M
1  2  Alex    L
1  3  Alex    L
2  4  Mark    R
2  5  Mark    R
2  6  Mark    R
3  7  John    M
```

**UPDATE:** метод [DataFrame.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) появился в Pandas 0.25.0, для более старых вырсий можно воспользоваться функцией [explode(df, lst_cols, fill_value='', preserve_index=False)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449726/5741205)

```
def explode(df, lst_cols, fill_value='', preserve_index=False):
    # make sure `lst_cols` is list-alike
    if (lst_cols is not None
        and len(lst_cols) > 0
        and not isinstance(lst_cols, (list, tuple, np.ndarray, pd.Series))):
        lst_cols = [lst_cols]
    # all columns except `lst_cols`
    idx_cols = df.columns.difference(lst_cols)
    # calculate lengths of lists
    lens = df[lst_cols[0]].str.len()
    # preserve original index values    
    idx = np.repeat(df.index.values, lens)
    # create "exploded" DF
    res = (pd.DataFrame({
                col:np.repeat(df[col].values, lens)
                for col in idx_cols},
                index=idx)
             .assign(**{col:np.concatenate(df.loc[lens>0, col].values)
                            for col in lst_cols}))
    # append those rows that have empty lists
    if (lens == 0).any():
        # at least one list in cells is empty
        res = (res.append(df.loc[lens==0, idx_cols], sort=False)
                  .fillna(fill_value))
    # revert the original index order
    res = res.sort_index()
    # reset index if requested
    if not preserve_index:        
        res = res.reset_index(drop=True)
    return res
```

PS по ссылке выше на оригинальный пост можно найти примеры использования данной функции...

Comment: Добрый день! Спасибо большое, но у меня не работает explode( Насколько понимаю, причина в старой версии Pandas, но оперативно обновить нет возможности. Может быть, есть другой способ?

Comment: @Kate, какая у вас версия Pandas?

Comment: Версия 0.24.2_____

Comment: @Kate, есть и другой способ - смотрите обновленный ответ)

Comment: Спасибо большое!)